# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/CORBA/iiop/ORB in WAS Liberty

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

I started using WAS Liberty 8.5 in my eclipse,when i try to deploy an application I am getting this error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/CORBA/iiop/ORB
```

I found that its due to the WAS runtime jar `ibmorb.jar` provided with WAS server install.

I dont know how to configure in WAS Liberty profile.Any clues.

Even i mentioned in the library path,but still error getting.

```
<variable name="DRIVER_PATH" value="C:\NovemberR2\DMS\deploy\lib"/>
<library id="db2Lib">
          <fileset dir="${DRIVER_PATH}" includes="com.ibm.ws.orb_8.5.0.jar classes12.jar oracleJDBC.jar ojdbc6.jar ojdbc14.jar ibmorbapi.jar ibmorb.jar"/>
</library>
```

The stacktrace is --->

```
here is the stack trace.    ...` 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/CORBA/iiop/ORB
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2685)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1620)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.getInitORBMethodForNonApplet(Helpers.java:411)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.getOrb(Helpers.java:390)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:462)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:128)
    orSourcesPropertyResolver.java:84)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:60)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:511)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$1.getProperty(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:135)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$1.getProperty(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:132)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:84)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getPropertyAsRawString(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:70)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver$1.resolvePlaceholder(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:207)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:147)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:204)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:178)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$2.resolveStringValue(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:801)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:962)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 63 more
```

Thanks for the hints,but i used to run this application well in WAS 8.0 server and IBM WAS JDK provide in built and i started migration to WAS 8.5 using liberty profile thought of experimenting it.

Comment: what's the stack trace of the Exception?  That will tell you what is trying to load it.

Comment: I edited the question with stack trace.

Comment: I think WAS JRE is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this answer would be helpful to others as it may be too late!
Try adding `com.ibm.ws.orb_8.5.0.jar` in the class path. This jar will be available under `<WAS_HOME>\AppServer\runtimes` . This will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here looks like you are using the JDK provided with WAS traditional to run a Liberty server.

The JDK that comes with WAS traditional is going to have extra stuff in it that is specifically for running with WAS traditional (it does not not support pluggable JDKs).

**Instead:**
Use a standard JDK to run your Liberty server.  You can get a standard JDK from IBM (not the one that comes with WAS traditional), Oracle, or OpenJDK.

Answer (score 0):

The question states that the application worked correctly on WAS 8.0. With WAS 8.5, you are now trying to run the same application on the Liberty Profile. The Liberty profile supports a subset of the functionality of the traditional WAS profile (now termed 'full profile').

As user @aguibert mentioned in their answer, you have to provide the Java runtime environment for the Liberty profile. This can be any compliant Java SE 6/7/8 JRE/JDK*. For the full profile, a different JDK is required; this is bundled with the installation package. This WebSphere JDK should contain the `ibmorb.jar` file.

Therefore, try running your application using the WAS 8.5 full profile. This should resolve the problem. You can also consider migrating to the latest version of WAS, which is v9.0.

Additional resource at IBM Knowledge Center: [Liberty profile overview](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/cwlp_about.html).

*Subject to [minimum supported Java levels](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/rwlp_restrict.html).